# Integrating differential algebraic equations / implicit ODEs (hopefully in Python)

Tags: ode, odeint, pde

I'm looking for ways to integrated differential algebraic equations that can't be rearranged into explicit ODEs, but have mixed product terms between variables and derivatives. For example, this is one such system, where x0, x1 are two variables, and x0_t, x1_t their time derivatives:

x0x0_t = 0.195 + 0.247 x0 + -0.045 x0x1 + -0.001 x1x1 + 0.035 x1x0_t + 0.013 x0x1x0_t + -0.136 x0x1x1_t + -0.218 x1x1x0_t

I've tried with diffeqpy and fipy with poor success, and I don't think it's feasible with odeint. I can also switch to Julia (which I haven't used yet) if needed.

Thank you so much in advance!

Best,
Luca

Comment: This is one differential equation in 2 variable. There is an additional equation missing to make this into a full ODE system or a DAE system.